# Error while Joining Tables using SQLAlchemy select and select_from with join function

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, database, sqlalchemy

I created two tables Customer and Order with data as below:
Customer:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Jane |
| 3 | Bob |

Order :

| id | product | customer_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | product_1 | 1 |
| 2 | product_2 | 2 |
| 3 | product_3 | 1 |
| 4 | product_4 | 3 |
| 5 | product_5 | 2 |

```
`
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, select
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///example.db', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()

class Customer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'customers'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    orders = relationship("Order", back_populates="customer")

class Order(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'orders'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    customer_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('customers.id'))
    product = Column(String)
    customer = relationship("Customer", back_populates="orders")

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

# Populate the database with sample data
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

customers = [Customer(name='John'), Customer(name='Jane'), Customer(name='Bob')]
session.add_all(customers)
session.commit()

orders = [
  Order(product='product_1', customer_id=customers[0].id),
  Order(product='product_2', customer_id=customers[1].id),
  Order(product='product_3', customer_id=customers[0].id),
  Order(product='product_4', customer_id=customers[2].id),
  Order(product='product_5', customer_id=customers[1].id)
]
session.add_all(orders)
session.commit()

# Perform a join query to retrieve data from multiple tables
stmt = select(Order.id, Order.product, Customer.name). \
       select_from(Order.join(Customer, Order.customer_id == Customer.id))

results = session.execute(stmt)

for row in results:
         print(row)

session.close()
```

`

Error:

> select_from(Order.join(Customer, Order.customer_id == Customer.id))
> AttributeError: type object 'Order' has no attribute 'join'

How do I add join statement here?

EDIT :  Just noticed session.add_all() statements is adding redundant data in the database. Customer table has 15 entries. Can you explain why is it happening?

Comment: Each call to the script is inserting new data that doesn't have a pre-existing primary key so new ones are generated each time.  That is why there are duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

`join()` should be chained onto `select_from()` instead of onto `Order`.

```py
stmt = select(Order.id, Order.product, Customer.name).select_from(Order).join(Customer, Order.customer_id == Customer.id)
```

This should also work because Sqlalchemy can infer the join condition on foreign keys:

```py
stmt = select(Order.id, Order.product, Customer.name).select_from(Order).join(Order.customer)
```